# How do I calculate the difficulty of a multi-sided encounter?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, encounter-design

From looking through the DMG for encounter building (p. 81-85), it seems clear to me that the rules for how to calculate encounter difficulty assume that there are only two sides in an encounter: PCs vs Monsters. However, I was wondering if there was a way to calculate encounter difficulty when there are more than two sides to the conflict.

I looked at the answers to [this question,](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70681/37082) (which does address a similar scenario to what I have in mind) however I am not satisfied with the answers since I feel that tweaking the difficulty "on the fly" would break the immersion of the scenario, as would having the NPCs drop everything and focus only on the PCs.

Comment: Sorry but as was actually explained in the comments of different question recently, we don't re-ask a question just because we "don't like" the answers. If you aren't satisfied with the current answers to a question then you can set a bounty on the question or comment on the Q or A asking for additional clarification. *If* you can [edit] this question to provide enough of a significant difference to the other question then we may be able to help. Note: it may be there's already enough of a significant difference to keep this Q open but we'll have to wait and see.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey I don't think there is that much of a difference (after waffling twice on which way it should go). The linked question does ask about how to calculate the encounter's difficulty ahead of time, just like this one does. (That the top-voted answer over there doesn't execute its frame challenge very well doesn't matter, IMO.) A bounty or just the increased exposure from this asking may be enough to see some better answers come in over there.